# How to restrict pull operation for specific folder in GITLAB?

Tags: java, gitlab

How can i restrict GIT PULL operation for specific folder in GIT LAB?

problem statement is i do not want others to pull the latest code from GIT LAB for certain amount of time.
Kindly help me out how can i implement this?

Comment: i think it would be easier if you better describe your problem so it will be easier to find an answer

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to just comit and not push, or use an other branch for your personnal work and then merge or rebase.